# How to inline css in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have used tables and aligned images in each row.
On key press I want to zoom the images at the center.
Here is the link:http://fiddle.jshell.net/7Wn47/

I want the below code to be put in single line

```
image1.style.width="600px";
image1.style.height="320px";
image1.style.transition="2s";
```

Something like:

```
image1.setAttribute('style', 'width: 600px; height: 320px; translate(0,150px);z index:1;transition: 2s;transition-delay: 4s');
```

But this is not working.
But if I use: -webkit-transform:scale(1)

instead of: width: 600px; height: 320px; it works, but doesn't overlap properly.

In my link:
Press key 1 to zoom first image-see how it zooms
Press key 2 to zoom second image- see how it zooms

There is a difference right?

I don't mind to stick with second one, but the bottom part of the image which is zooming is awkward(Hope it could zoom like top part of the image)

kindly help

Answer (score 2):

Try using cssText, incase if you try to change the css in stylesheet

```
image1.style.cssText = 'width: 600px; height: 320px; 
                        translate(0,150px);z index:1;transition: 2s;transition-delay: 4s';
```

Incase jQuery

```
$('#image1id').css({
  width: 600px,
  height: 320px,
  translate(0,150px),
  zIndex:1,
  transition: 2s,
  transitionDelay: 4s
});
```

Comment: That was good, can `scale` thing work the same way? I mean the overlapping part can it zoom like the top part of the image while zooming?